# Is there a specific way to user input a value using a separator such as "#"?

Tags: c#

I have the below code which is supposed to ask the user to input various integers separated by `#` (like `1#2#3##2` and so on). It is then supposed to find the values in the sequence entered that have repeats and display it like "the sequence contains 2 repeated value."

However I am not sure if the code I have used to separate the user entered value is correct as it displays an error:

[image: image of the error]

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        // Keep the following line intact 
        Console.WriteLine("===========================");

        // Insert your solution here.     
               
        // user input gets the input from the user 
       
        // regarding a line where integers are separated by # 
       
        String userInput;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter single line containing a list of integers, separated by '#':");

        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // splitting the userInput into Array of Strings  
        if (userInput != null)
        {
            // splitting the userInput by # 
            String[] numberStrings = userInput.Split("#");

            // numbers list contain the list of unique numbers
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

            // takes count of duplicate numbers 
            int totalDuplicateNumbers = 0;

            // adding the number string to the list after converting to int
        
            for (int i = 0; i < numberStrings.Length; i++)
            {
                numbers.Add(Int32.Parse(numberStrings[i]));
            }

            // now sorting the number list     
            numbers.Sort();

            bool duplicatePresent = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1])
                {
                    if (!duplicatePresent)
                    {
                        duplicatePresent = true;

                        totalDuplicateNumbers += 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    duplicatePresent = false;
                }
            }

            // display result        
    
            Console.WriteLine($"The sequence contains {totalDuplicateNumbers} repeated values.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
        }

        // Keep the following lines intact
   
        Console.WriteLine("===========================");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you add the totally irrelevant tag for the C language? C is almost as far from C# as it's possible to get.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: I don't understand why so many people are apparently confused when they add an image and it says "enter image description here" and think that not entering an image description there is the best and most appropriate course of action.

Comment: If you had read the documentation for the `string.Split` method then you would have had your answer. ALWAYS read the relevant documentation. Even Intellisense is telling you: it's expecting a `char`, not a `string`.

Comment: Which means you can take this as an example from which you can practice how to read (and understand) error messages. Also, how to investigate in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not correct. `Split` expects one or more *characters* to split by. You passed a string. Pass a character, like this:

```
String[] numberStrings = userInput.Split('#');
```

Please note that this solution *will fail* on your test input of

> 1#2#3##2

Because that means that there are the strings `"1", "2", "3", "", "2"` and `""` will fail in your subsequent parsing attempt.

You may want to try

```
String[] numberStrings = userInput.Split('#', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This *removes* the empty, non-number entries. Whether that is what your exercise wants you to do, or if you should do something else with the empty input, is something only you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

**numberStrings = numberStrings.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();**

*This will avoid empty entries*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).